# Program.vshost.exe Error Preventing Running Program

Tags: c#, visual-studio, vshost.exe

I've been moving files around from my debug folder in an attempt to open the executable for my program from a different location.  This seemed to have screwed things up, and I'd like to know how to fix them.

The exact error reads as follows:

"Visual Studio could not copy a support file to this location:\Program.vshost.exe'. Please verify the path exists and is writeable."

And ideas on how to fix this?

Comment: Right click on the project/solution -> Properties -> Debug -> Uncheck "Enable visual studio hosting process"

Comment: Can you post an answer for this question so I can check it as the accepted solution?  It worked perfectly! :)

Comment: Also would suggest retagging your project with "Visual Studio"..

Comment: I added the tag Bharath, thanks for the reminder

Comment: This error also happened to me, when I accidentally had more than one copy of the same solution open (two instances of visual studio). Simply closing one resolves it.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Right click on the project/solution -> Properties -> Debug -> Uncheck "Enable visual studio hosting process"

Comment: On Visual Studio 2010, the solution doesn't have a "Debug" tab. You have to do it on the project.

Comment: @MGranja same problem applies when using studio 2005. Cheers for that pointer

Comment: what are the pros/cons of using/not using the VS hosting process?

Answer (score 0):

Also you can terminate it from Task Manager. if running Win 6 or 7 use end process from admin previlige

Comment: When I do that, VS always restarts the process when I build the solution.